# Does Geany or Gedit provide a browser protocol in the way Textmate does with txmt://?

Tags: programming, gedit

Textmate on the Mac can be bound to the txmt protocol, meaning that development frameworks (such as the Play Framework) can be configured to use this to display error messages. If a stacktrace appears, each line of the stacktrace is a URL of the format (I'm guessing):

```
txmt:///home/myuser/projects/myproject/ProblemFile.java:123
```

(where 123 is the line number).

Clicking this opens the file in Textmate.

Is this possible with Gedit, Geany or another programmer's text editor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's possible to easily create new protocol handlers in Gnome, all you have to do is add some keys in gconf.

In a terminal, type:

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/foo/command '/path/to/app %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/foo/enabled --type Boolean true
```

Replace foo on both lines with the protocol you want to register and /path/to/app with the path to the application you want to run. 
(from : http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol#All_Firefox_versions )

Comment: concerning the line number part, it depends on the editor. I know you can open a file on a particular line number with vim but I don't know if gedit or geany support that feature.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer does not work on 11.04.

Here's my solution for gedit on 11.04: http://rystraum.com/blog/2012/05/rails-footnotes-with-gedit/

TLDR; version:

1. Create `/usr/share/applications/foo-uri.desktop`:

   > ```
   > [Desktop Entry]
   > Name=Foo
   > GenericName=Foo
   > Comment=Open foo links in Gedit
   > TryExec=open_gedit
   > Exec=open_gedit %u
   > Terminal=false
   > Type=Application
   > MimeType=x-scheme-handler/foo
   > NoDisplay=true
   > ```
2. Run `sudo update-desktop-database`
3. `open_gedit` script inside location that is in $PATH

   > ```
   > #!/bin/bash
   > FILE=$1
   > FILE=${FILE/foo\:\/\//}
   > LINE=$(echo $FILE | grep -o "\&line=[0-9]\+")
   > LINE=$(echo $LINE | grep -o "[0-9]\+")
   > FILE=$(echo $FILE | grep -o "\(.\+\)\&")
   > FILE=$(echo $FILE | cut -d'&' -f1)
   > gedit +$LINE $FILE
   > ```
4. Call as foo:///path/to/file&line=299

Comment: Great Solution! but to make it work for me i've edited 3rd line to be `FILE=${FILE/txmt\:\/\/open\?url\=file\:\/\//}`

Answer (score 0):

My best shot using Python (probably misses some edge cases):

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/geany/command ' python -c "import urlparse;import sys;import pipes;url=\"http\"+sys.argv[1][5:];import os; up=urlparse.urlparse(url);os.system(\"geany \"+(pipes.quote(\"/\"+up.netloc+up.path)+\" --socket-file /tmp/geany --line \" + pipes.quote(up.query)))" %s' --type String
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/url-handlers/geany/enabled --type Boolean true
```

Will start opening `geany://home/www/index.php?239` as `/home/www/index.php` at line `239` using `/tmp/geany` as socket (to avoid opening many instances of geany)