# txmt URL Handler for Chromium does not work

Tags: chromium, gconf, protocol, xdg-open

I used the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15492/does-geany-or-gedit-provide-a-browser-protocol-in-the-way-textmate-does-with-txmt) but it won't open when I click those links in my browser. I can go to terminal, and type xdg-open and then paste the txmt link, and it will work, so I know my script (a ruby script @ usr/bin/local) is working correctly and the protocol handler is set right in gconf.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using RVM, ruby version manager.
My script to load gedit and parse the txmt handler is written in Ruby.
In whatever capacity `xdg-open` is launched by Chromium, it does not have access to the currently active ruby in RVM via the `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` hashbang.
Research into RVM showed that there is a `rvm-auto-ruby` which points to the currently active --system ruby in RVM.

Running `which rvm-auto-ruby` gives me `/home/jake/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby` so in `gconf-editor`, I put this for the handler application:

```
/home/jake/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby /usr/local/bin/txmt_handler "%s"
```

And now it works!